# Regex difference between PHP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I've found a bug in the lexer I wrote some time ago, and it appears to be in my regex. I use regex101 a lot, and I often forget to change from PHP to Javascript on the left. Either way, here is my regex:

```
/([\w\.]*)([()]*)/g
```

Now, aside from matching a whole lot of nothing, I should match the string:

```
(!one || !two) && three
```

...on:

`(`, `one`, `two`, `)`, `three`

In PHP, this regex works just the way I want it to!

In Javascript, it doesn't!!!! Why the heck does Javascript give me this?!?!

`(`, `one`, `two)`, `three`

*Our parts `two` and `)` wound up in the same match...*

So, **my question is**, how could I match the string:

```
(!one || !two) && three
```

...as:

`(`, `one`, `two`, `)`, `three`

..in Javascript using a `string.match()` on the regex?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, my question is, how could I match the string:
>
> ```
> (!one || !two) && three
> ```
>
> ...as:
>
> `(`, `one`, `two`, `)`, `three`
>
> ..in Javascript using regex?

As follows:

```
"(!one || !two) && three".match(/[\w\.]+|[()]/g);

["(", "one", "two", ")", "three"]
```

> Why the heck does Javascript give me this?!?!

Your original regex `/([\w\.]*)([()]*)/g` matches 0 or more word characters or dots followed by 0 or more brackets (`*` means 0 or more). You're actually getting not just things like `two)` but also lots of empty strings. To get what you're asking for, you need to use alternation, as in the example above: you want either word chars or brackets.

I'm guessing you probably want at least one word char and only one bracket at a time, so I've amended the quantifiers to `+` on the word char option and nothing on the bracket option.

Comment: Absolutely fantastic! Thank you! This is exactly what I needed, and thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

The root cause is that this regex can match an empty string and different engines handle those situations differently. In JS, you most probably use the regex101 way to manually advance the index if a zero-length match is found without checking if the next character is a start of a valid match.

To work around this, you need to make sure your regex does not match an empty string. Thus, you can use alternation and use one part with `+` and the other with `*` quantifier, swapping them in the alternative branch:

```
([\w\.]+)([()]*)|([\w\.]*)([()]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wO2kI8/1). In JS code, you need to apply some logic to get the right values:

```js
var re = /([\w\.]+)([()]*)|([\w\.]*)([()]+)/g; 
var str = '(!one || !two) && three';
var res = [];
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m[4]) {  res.push(m[4]); } 
    else if (m[3]) {  res.push(m[3]); } 
    else if (m[2]) {  res.push(m[2]); } 
    else {  res.push(m[1]); } 
}
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4) + "</pre>";
```

Comment: Just a comment: the `.`, inside a character class, does not have to be escaped, but some of use like to play it double safe :)

Comment: I really appreciate the initiative you put forth in this! Unfortunately, your regex is invalid. Thanks for the effort though

Comment: *your regex is invalid* is not true at all.

Comment: Yes it is Wiktor, try using it in a JS application. `two` and `)` are included in the same match, just like my issue. Also, his code snippet is excluding the `two` somehow. The results are supposed to be `(`, `one`, `two`, `)`, `three`. His snippet provides `(`, `one`, `)`, and `three`. That is, by definition, _invalid_. When I used his regex in my application, I got `(`, `one`, `two)`, and `three` from it. Still invalid, yet akwardly different from his snippet.

Comment: I have used it in a JS application (see the code in my answer), and it is your regex in a JS usable form. The answer you accepted is not a solution, it is a workaround for the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, your answer gives the wrong results. Also, the answer I accepted gives me exactly the correct results instead of iterating over a set of empty stings trying to pull the correct results out. I'm sorry, but I'm sure that the use of a while loop is more of a work around than the correct regex.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple one:

```
\w+|\(|\)
```

This is three different values separated by the 'or' operand '|'

The three values it is looking for are:

1. Any alphanumeric characters where there are at least one '\w+'
2. An opening parenthesis, remember to escape it with a backslash '('
3. A closing parenthesis, also escaping it ')'

This will then match each single word and both opening and closing parenthesis as separate matches.

Or you could use the brackets for the parenthesis, since they are both single characters and thus remove the need for the extra escapes.

```
\w+|[()]
```

Use which one you find the clearest as it will help with future maintenance.

Comment: That is interesting! Thank you!

Comment: I missed the period (or decimal) you had in the original, and i see someone already gave you the answer that would match three.four as one match ... [\w\.]+|[()]